# Persistence for childAdded o childRemoved on forenses?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im developing an app for transport. The idea is a driver can take services which clients have already asked. So, when a driver aceppt a service from a client, it will remove  the service from “Analizable services” on firebase database, I have an observer to listen when a service is removed and tell the client its service has been taken, that works perfectly.

Now imagine this situation, a driver take the service but the client is not connect to internet in that momment, so he will not “listen” the child removed and whenever he connect again, he wont know its service has been taken. I know firebase offers “persistence” but I am not pretty sure about how to use it in this specific case.

This is part of my code:

```
RefConductores.child(IDUsuarioActual).child("Servicios Tomados").observe(.childAdded)
        { (snapshot) in

            let key = snapshot.value as? String

            if key != nil
            {

                if let i = MisServicios.Instancia.VectorMisServicios.index(where: { $0.Key == key })
                {
                    MisServicios.Instancia.VectorMisServicios.remove(at: i)
                    Alertas.Instancia.CrearNotificaciones(Tipo: 1)
                }

              MisServicios.Instancia.CargarMisServicios(IDServicio: key!)
            }

        }
```

It works perfectly, there is not mistake. What Im trying to figure out is how to make it work when users do not have internet connection. When a driver take the service (since driver's mobile), in costumer application (in costumer's mobile), it will be executed the code presented (That work perfectly if costumer has a properly internet connection). My question is: Imagine the client does not have internet connection, he won't be able to listen "childAdded" and when he connect again to internet, the child will be already on "Servicios Tomados" node, but he will never know about it. How can I solve this issue?

Thank everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase database synchronizes state, it does not necessarily synchronize all state changes.

If you want to communicate the fact that a ride was taken to the clients, you should *store* the fact that a ride was taken in the database. So instead of (only) removing the rode from "Analizable services”, you'll want to store the information in a "Rides taken" node (too).

Comment: Hello Frank, thank u for ur answer. Actually, Im storing the services taken on “rides taken”, anyway how would I inform the client its service has been taken?, I mean if a child is added to this node and the client is not connected to internet, he wont “listen” when the child got added.

Comment: It's really hard to understand the problem in the way you're describing it now, which is why I explained how the system works. Can you share the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I have added part of the code in my question, I would appreciate it you could read it.
Thank u Frank

Comment: Since you're only observing `.childAdded`, you will never know when a node gets removed. To catch those, also observe `.childRemoved`.

Comment: I have not problem with .childAdded or .childRemoved. It works just perfect. What I want to know is something I read about "Persistence", I am not pretty sure how to configure "Persistence" to listen for child Added or Removed.

Comment: Persistence is a global flag. When you turn it on, the state is persisted to disk. When you then restart the app, it will first read data from disk, and only then connect to the server for updates. **But** even if you don't enable disk persistence, as long as the listener stays active (i.e. the app stays open),  when the client reestablishes the connection the `.childAdded` will fire for any new children that were added while the app was offline.